# Burninate the "php" tag

Tags: support, burninate-request

[php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) is used from 153 questions. Considering that Drupal is a PHP CMS, the tag should be burninated. It could be used for many different questions, such as:

- Questions about a Drupal function
- Questions about specific code required to implement a specific feature
- Questions about a PHP code used for a module that doesn't work as it is currently implemented
- Questions about the PHP code used for a theme that doesn't work as expected

[php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) would be used in many questions asked on *Drupal Answers*, as Drupal is written in PHP. There are also questions about JavaScript, but there are less questions about Javascript that are specific to Drupal than questions about Drupal that could be tagged [php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) simply for the fact the question is about PHP code used for a Drupal theme, module, or distribution.

As side note, there is [php-classes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php-classes) that can be used about PHP classes implemented in Drupal.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, let's get rid of it

Answer (score -1):

There are also a considerable number of questions in which the author explicitly requests that the answer be code/not be code. Is it not useful to distinguish?

Comment: This is a valid point, however, if this is the case then it should be made obvious in the question title rather than adding a PHP tag that is essentially useless due to there being a 95% chance the question will involve some PHP

Comment: True. Perhaps it would be more useful to have tags delineating programmer questions from non-programmer, site builder/user questions? I'm thinking that would be of particular benefit to non-coders looking for questions they can answer.

Comment: For that, there is no need to use a tag, especially a tag like [tag:php] which would be understood as "this is a question about PHP code," rather than "I need code, not a module." Considering that a question is not just for the OP, but also for future readers, such tag would not be helpful. I could answer a question about code saying there is a module that implements that code, and exposes an API for other modules. Even if the OP asks for code, my answer would be perfectly acceptable.